# Convert Arraylist<subclass> to ArrayList<parent>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists that contain `Parent` and `Child` class which `Child` extents `Parent` and `Second` extends `First`

```
public First(ArrayList<Parent> parents)
{
    // Parent Class's constructor
}
```

second class's constructor

```
public Second(ArrayList<Child> child)
{
    super(child);
    // child class's constructor take ArrayList<Child>
}
```

Is it possible to cast `ArrayList<Child>` to `ArrayList<Parent>`?

Comment: You'll have to loop over every value of the list and cast it.

Comment: How about `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`?

Comment: Or you could declare your method parameter as `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`, perhaps? It's not really clear what you want to do. Do you want to pass an ArrayList of Child to First?

Comment: Init a `Second` which is able to take `ArrayList<Child>`. As `Parent` and `Child`, `First` and `Second` are quite similar, so I am looking for a way to subclass them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit goes for Churro.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Second(ArrayList<? extends Parent> child)
{
    super((ArrayList<Parent>) child);
}
```

Comment: How does this solve your problem? It seems from the question that you really need the element type of your list to be `Child` and you are losing that here.

Answer (score 8):

This is the way to cast from Parent to child

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Foo> parentArray = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    parentArray.add(new Foo("tooLazy"));
    parentArray.add(new Foo("tooAdd"));
    parentArray.add(new Foo("tooMoreFields"));
    ArrayList<Boo> childArray =  (ArrayList<Boo>) ((ArrayList<?>) parentArray);
}
```

And this is the way to cast from Child to parent

```
//Boo extends Foo BTW
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Boo> parentArray = new ArrayList<Boo>();
    parentArray.add(new Boo("tooLazy"));
    parentArray.add(new Boo("tooAdd"));
    parentArray.add(new Boo("tooMoreFields"));
    ArrayList<Foo> childArray =  (ArrayList<Foo>) ((ArrayList<?>) parentArray);
}
```

Comment: There will be a unchecked warning.

Comment: Yeah, but what is the big deal if you already know that those classes are parent and child?. Sure, there are better ways like `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`.

Comment: Ya you are right, both `ArrayList<? extends Parent>` and `(ArrayList<Foo>) ((ArrayList<?>) parentArray)` are good. Thanks

Comment: The big deal is that it is not type safe.  In the class `First` I could add to the list `parents` an instance of `BlackSheep` if `BlackSheep extends Parent`.  The compiler won't stop me from doing that.

Comment: This humble monkey coder kneels on your wisdom almighty @JudgeMental (Really, your explanation is right. Doing like I do is the Billy way)

Comment: @JudgeMental I can see why casting a parent to a child can be dangerous. However, it should be safe to cast a child to a parent, right?

Comment: @NurShomik No, because lists are mutable.  Once I "up-cast" the element type of the list I can start adding things to it that I should not be allowed to add.  Immutable lists, such as the ones you might find in Scala, are safe to "up-cast" in either the element type or the list type.

Comment: @JudgeMental OK, got it. So the problem always occurs when list is of parent type. As parent may have many other sub-types that can be added to the list - either before down-casting to child, or after up-casting to parent. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

use [this.addAll(child)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in the constructor of `second`.

Its not casting but it will create a new `Arraylist` with the contents of the `child`

Answer (score 0):

The only way this relationship is kosher is if, in the constructor of `Parent`, you are not modifying the input list in any way except perhaps to clear it or add nulls to it. In that case you might as well make the argument type of the constructor of `First` be `ArrayList<? extends Parent>`.  Then there is no need to copy the array or do unsafe casts.

I should add that unless you are relying on specific properties of the `ArrayList` class, `List<? extends Parent>` would be even better.

Comment: But this is sacrifice the type check in First?

Comment: How so?  First will only accept a list whose elements are all of some class Parent or more specific than Parent. That allows a list of Child to be passed in too. According to your question that is your intention.